# what is the syntax for adding newline to this list expression

Tags: python, list, file-io

So I am trying to write a few different values of this list to a few specific lines of this text file essentially replacing them. I got a tip on my last [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73776306/python-writing-to-file-is-not-writing-as-expected/73776404#73776404) to seperate the lines in this output I need to do \n however I am struggling to implement this within this list expression. If I do it within the writeline command it gives me every line within the file with an extra whitespace line. If anyone has any ideas please let me know. this is the code:

```
def writeAPconstants(roll_pred , roll_resp, roll_error, roll_rate, roll_tunetime):





# takes line index to map function inputs as new autopilot constant values
APlist[line_index[0]]  = "P acf/_ott_phi_sec_into_future" ' ' + roll_pred
APlist[line_index[1]] = "P acf/_ott_roll_response" + ' ' + roll_resp
APlist[line_index[2]] = "P acf/_ott_phi_deg_off_for_full_def" + ' ' + roll_error
APlist[line_index[3]] = "P acf/_ott_roll_rate" + ' ' + roll_rate
APlist[line_index[4]] = "P acf/_ott_phi_sec_to_tune" + ' ' + roll_tunetime
APfile.seek(0)
APfile.writelines(APlist)
APfile.truncate()

#closes file
APfile.close()
```

Comment: @Matiiss `writelines()` doesn't add newlines. That's the problem.

Comment: Will you write a simpler piece of code that illustrates the exact problem you are trying to solve? There seems to be a lot of extra code here that doesn't have anything to do with your question (such as all the `if` statements). Then give an example output and explain how it is different from what you want.

Comment: p.s. Use `enumerate()` to get indexes rather than doing a linear search with `APlist.index()` multiple times.

Comment: thank you I totally forgot about enumerate for some reason when writing this I usually only think about it during list comp for some reason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lines returned by `readlines()` have newlines appended. You need to add newlines to the end of each string you assign to a list member.

```
APlist[line_index[0]]  = "P acf/_ott_phi_sec_into_future" ' ' + roll_pred + '\n'
APlist[line_index[1]] = "P acf/_ott_roll_response" + ' ' + roll_resp + '\n'
APlist[line_index[2]] = "P acf/_ott_phi_deg_off_for_full_def" + ' ' + roll_error + '\n'
APlist[line_index[3]] = "P acf/_ott_roll_rate" + ' ' + roll_rate + '\n'
APlist[line_index[4]] = "P acf/_ott_phi_sec_to_tune" + ' ' + roll_tunetime + '\n'
```